# 301 Moved Permanently for Spring reference in Context.xml

Tags: spring, http-status-code-301, context.xml

I am using Spring in my application and have reference in Context.xml. When i tried curl http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee from my server. It throws 301 error.

I also tried curl http://spring.io/schema/jee this redirects me to the page.

Kindly advice if we need to update our Spring URL to spring.io

Comment: 301 is not an error, it's a redirect response. Do you get any errors when executing your application?

Comment: I am not getting any Error, but wondering if we need to update the reference. A friend of mine saying He is getting error due to this.

Comment: Well, "if it ain't broken, don't fix it". And the errors of your friend most probably have another cause, because usually all the schema files are shipped in the JAR files of Spring, and the url is only for identification.

Comment: No you shouldn't. not should you attempt what you did. The resolution for the xsd is always local (not internet based) as it will always be retrieved from the jar file it is contained in.